# How do I use regular expressions with Nant 0.91 calling a C#

Tags: c#, nant

In Nant 0.85 you could call C# scripts and it would import the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace. Now in 0.91 that is no longer the case, and I can't seem to to import `System.Text.RegularExpressions` properly. I've tried adding the following

```xml
<imports>
  <import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
</imports>
```

And I see `System.Text.RegularExpressions` get added to a using statement, but I keep getting the error:

> The type or namespace name 'RegularExpressions' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Text' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a reference to `System.dll`:

```xml
<references>
  <include name="System.dll" />
</references>
```